# Set notation: Difference between using spot/bullet, vertical bar '|' and or colon ':'

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have seen all three being used, sometimes two of them in the same set definition:

- mid: '$\mid$'
- spot/bullet: '$\bullet$'
- colon: '$:$'

Is there a difference between the three and when should each one of these used to specify a set?

Thanks.

Comment: I would hope you didn't see them used _in the same text_...

Comment: I have never seen a bullet used for this. Where have you?

Comment: I see the bullet being used in Z notation (https://staff.washington.edu/jon/z/text.html) and figured that use came out of set notation as that is what it is based on. Maybe bullet is just unique to Z...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’ve never seen the bullet used, but I’ve seen notation of the form $\{x \in A \mid P(x)\}$ and $\{x \in A : P(x)\}$ used to denote the same set, which exists by the axiom of separation. Similar notation exists for sets formed using the axiom of replacement. I’ve never seen the bullet used in this context.

The meanings are the same. I typically choose one or the other based on whether I’m using one of the symbols to mean something else. The $\mid$ bar can also mean “is a factor of”, so I would denote the set of even numbers by $\{x \in \mathbb{Z} : 2 \mid x\}$. On the other hand, $:$ is often used to describe the domain and codomain of functions, so I might describe a set of monotonic functions as $\{f : A \to B \mid \forall w, x \in A, (w \leq x \to f(w) \leq f(x))\}$.

Comment: And what if you're using both of them to mean something else?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Then you’re out of luck, I guess. There’s no law saying you can’t use the same symbol twice in an expression to mean two different things, however.

Comment: @RobertIsrael An alternative it to just write s.t. i.e instead of \vert write \text{ s.t. }